# Filling a column based on the value of another column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, interpolation, shift

I have data as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(amount_of_categories = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), municipality = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Area A", 
"Area B"), class = "factor"), type= c("cat_1", "cat_1", 
"cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", 
"cat_1", NA, "cat_2", NA, NA, "cat_2", "cat_2", "cat_2", "cat_2", 
"cat_2")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

    amount_of_categories municipality  type
 1:                    2       Area A cat_1
 2:                    2       Area A cat_1
 3:                    2       Area A cat_1
 4:                    2       Area A cat_1
 5:                    2       Area A cat_1
 6:                    2       Area A cat_1
 7:                    2       Area A cat_1
 8:                    2       Area A cat_1
 9:                    2       Area A cat_1
10:                    2       Area A cat_1
11:                    2       Area A cat_1
12:                    2       Area A  <NA>
13:                    2       Area A cat_2
14:                    1       Area B  <NA>
15:                    1       Area B  <NA>
16:                    1       Area B cat_2
17:                    1       Area B cat_2
18:                    1       Area B cat_2
19:                    1       Area B cat_2
20:                    1       Area B cat_2
```

The idea is to create a new column `type_estimation`, which replaces the `NA`'s in the `type` column, with the right type. The right type can only be established if there is only one category (`amount_of_categories==1`) for that `Area`. So it should fill the last two `NA`'s but not the first.

I tried:

```
dat <- setDT(dat)[is.na(type) & amount_of_categories==1, type_estimation:= shift(type), by="municipality"]
```

But this does not work. What is right syntax here?

Desired outcome:

```
    amount_of_categories municipality  type  type_estimation
 1:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 2:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 3:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 4:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 5:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 6:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 7:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 8:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
 9:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
10:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
11:                    2       Area A cat_1            cat_1
12:                    2       Area A  <NA>             <NA> 
13:                    2       Area A cat_2            cat_2
14:                    1       Area B  <NA>            cat_2
15:                    1       Area B  <NA>            cat_2
16:                    1       Area B cat_2            cat_2
17:                    1       Area B cat_2            cat_2
18:                    1       Area B cat_2            cat_2
19:                    1       Area B cat_2            cat_2
20:                    1       Area B cat_2            cat_2
```

## EDIT:

I tried to come up with a situation in which the solution provided by Waldi could lead to an issue. After thinking about it for a bit I realised this would be the case if:

1. `dat[,estimation:=zoo::na.locf(type)]` fills with the wrong type, because the last observation is of `Area A` is carried forward, to the first observation of `Area B` and
2. `Area B` has only one category, so that `[amount_of_categories!=1&is.na(type) ,estimation:=NA][]` does make this value `NA`.

In the example data:

```
dat <- structure(list(amount_of_categories = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), municipality = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Area A", 
"Area B"), class = "factor"), type= c("cat_1", "cat_1", 
"cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", "cat_1", 
"cat_1", NA, "cat_2", NA, NA, "cat_3", "cat_3", "cat_3", "cat_3", 
"cat_3")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

   amount_of_categories municipality  type estimation
 1:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 2:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 3:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 4:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 5:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 6:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 7:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 8:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
 9:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
10:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
11:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
12:                    2       Area A  <NA>       <NA>
13:                    2       Area A cat_2      cat_2
14:                    1       Area B  <NA>      cat_2
15:                    1       Area B  <NA>      cat_2
16:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
17:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
18:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
19:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
20:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
```

As Waldi already pointed out, this issue cannot be fixed by using:

```
dat[,estimation:=zoo::na.locf(type), by="municipality"][amount_of_categories!=1&is.na(type) ,estimation:=NA][]
```

Any solution for this issue would still be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, which should be the replacement? I mean, how can we know if it is `cat_1` or `cat_2`?

Comment: @R18 For Area B, there is only one option because `amount_of_categories==1`, so it has to be `cat2`.

Comment: @Tom, why is `estimation = 'cat3'` in your last example?

Comment: Hey Waldi. It is because, for `Area B` it says that the amount of categories is 1. So because of that knowledge and the fact that for  `Area B` the `type` is `cat_3`, the others also have to be `cat_3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two steps:

```
dat[,estimation:=zoo::na.locf(type)][amount_of_categories!=1&is.na(type) ,estimation:=NA][]

    amount_of_categories municipality   type estimation
                   <int>       <fctr> <char>     <char>
 1:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 2:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 3:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 4:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 5:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 6:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 7:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 8:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 9:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
10:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
11:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
12:                    2       Area A   <NA>       <NA>
13:                    2       Area A  cat_2      cat_2
14:                    1       Area B   <NA>      cat_2
15:                    1       Area B   <NA>      cat_2
16:                    1       Area B  cat_2      cat_2
17:                    1       Area B  cat_2      cat_2
18:                    1       Area B  cat_2      cat_2
19:                    1       Area B  cat_2      cat_2
20:                    1       Area B  cat_2      cat_2
    amount_of_categories municipality   type estimation
```

Note that I used `zoo::na.locf` because `data.table::nafill(type='locf')` doesn't yet work with characters.

An alternative approach by `municipality` with `na.fill` following you edit (example 2):

```
dat[,estimation:=zoo::na.fill(type,fill=type[which.max(!is.na(type))]),by=municipality][amount_of_categories!=1&is.na(type) ,estimation:=NA][]

   amount_of_categories municipality   type estimation
                   <int>       <fctr> <char>     <char>
 1:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 2:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 3:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 4:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 5:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 6:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 7:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 8:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
 9:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
10:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
11:                    2       Area A  cat_1      cat_1
12:                    2       Area A   <NA>       <NA>
13:                    2       Area A  cat_2      cat_2
14:                    1       Area B   <NA>      cat_3
15:                    1       Area B   <NA>      cat_3
16:                    1       Area B  cat_3      cat_3
17:                    1       Area B  cat_3      cat_3
18:                    1       Area B  cat_3      cat_3
19:                    1       Area B  cat_3      cat_3
20:                    1       Area B  cat_3      cat_3
    amount_of_categories municipality   type estimation
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Waldi. Very interesting solution. I wanted to ask you if it is possible to fill with `zoo::na.locf(type)` by `municipality`, but looking at it, it does not even seem necessary, because the columns that will be filled incorrectly will be set to NA anyway.

Comment: by `municipality` is possible, but the 2 `NA`s won't disappear because `Area B` starts with them.

Comment: Hey Waldi, thanks again for your answer. I was thinking whether there was not a case in which your solution could fail. After some thinking I came up with a case and made an EDIT about it. Do you think there is a possible quick fix for this, or should I ask a new question?

Comment: I believe, Waldi's answer can be fixed w.r.t. to the edited question by `setDT(dat)[, estimation := zoo::na.locf(type, na.rm = FALSE), by = municipality][amount_of_categories != 1 & is.na(type) , estimation := NA][]`: (a) `na.locf()` is done groupwise for each municipality and (b) the `na.rm = FALSE` parameter avoids errors if the first value of `type` in a group is NA.

Comment: @Tom, see my edit which might answer your question, provided you clarify category of lines 14 and 15 in your last example.

Answer (score 1):

Does this approach leveraging `unique()` and join help with both cases?

```
unique(
  dat[amount_of_categories==1 & !is.na(type), .(municipality,type_estimation=type)]
)[dat, on=.(municipality)][is.na(type_estimation),type_estimation:=type][]
```

Output for example 1:

```
    municipality type_estimation amount_of_categories   type
          <fctr>          <char>                <int> <char>
 1:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 2:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 3:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 4:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 5:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 6:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 7:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 8:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 9:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
10:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
11:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
12:       Area A            <NA>                    2   <NA>
13:       Area A           cat_2                    2  cat_2
14:       Area B           cat_2                    1   <NA>
15:       Area B           cat_2                    1   <NA>
16:       Area B           cat_2                    1  cat_2
17:       Area B           cat_2                    1  cat_2
18:       Area B           cat_2                    1  cat_2
19:       Area B           cat_2                    1  cat_2
20:       Area B           cat_2                    1  cat_2
```

Output for example 2:

```
    municipality type_estimation amount_of_categories   type
          <fctr>          <char>                <int> <char>
 1:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 2:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 3:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 4:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 5:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 6:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 7:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 8:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
 9:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
10:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
11:       Area A           cat_1                    2  cat_1
12:       Area A            <NA>                    2   <NA>
13:       Area A           cat_2                    2  cat_2
14:       Area B           cat_3                    1   <NA>
15:       Area B           cat_3                    1   <NA>
16:       Area B           cat_3                    1  cat_3
17:       Area B           cat_3                    1  cat_3
18:       Area B           cat_3                    1  cat_3
19:       Area B           cat_3                    1  cat_3
20:       Area B           cat_3                    1  cat_3
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to create a *look-up table* for the relevant cases which is used in an *update join*:

```
library(data.table)
lut <- setDT(dat)[amount_of_categories == 1, first(na.omit(type)), by = municipality]
dat[, estimation := type][lut, on = .(municipality), estimation := V1][]
```

#### Result for example 1

> ```
>     amount_of_categories municipality  type estimation
>  1:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  2:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  3:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  4:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  5:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  6:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  7:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  8:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  9:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
> 10:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
> 11:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
> 12:                    2       Area A  <NA>       <NA>
> 13:                    2       Area A cat_2      cat_2
> 14:                    1       Area B  <NA>      cat_2
> 15:                    1       Area B  <NA>      cat_2
> 16:                    1       Area B cat_2      cat_2
> 17:                    1       Area B cat_2      cat_2
> 18:                    1       Area B cat_2      cat_2
> 19:                    1       Area B cat_2      cat_2
> 20:                    1       Area B cat_2      cat_2
> ```

#### Result for example 2

> ```
>     amount_of_categories municipality  type estimation
>  1:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  2:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  3:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  4:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  5:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  6:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  7:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  8:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
>  9:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
> 10:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
> 11:                    2       Area A cat_1      cat_1
> 12:                    2       Area A  <NA>       <NA>
> 13:                    2       Area A cat_2      cat_2
> 14:                    1       Area B  <NA>      cat_3
> 15:                    1       Area B  <NA>      cat_3
> 16:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
> 17:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
> 18:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
> 19:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
> 20:                    1       Area B cat_3      cat_3
> ```

#### Explanation

1. For each `municipality` *with only one category* the first non-NA element of `type` is picked for the *look-up table* `lut`.
2. A new column `estimate` is created in `dat` as a full copy of `type`.
3. In the *update join* all entries in `estimate` are replaced by the value from `lut` *only for the matching* `municipality`.

This approach is somehow similar to [langtang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72127231/3817004) but differs in implementation details.

#### N.B.: Updating column `type` directly

The OP has requested to create a separate column `estimate`. However, column type can be updated directly which streamlines the code:

```
dat[lut, on = .(municipality), type := V1][]
```